# Replace UITextView selected text with NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to replace some text that was selected inside a `UITextView` with some `NSAttributedString` but only the following method is available:

```
textView.replace(UITextRange, withText: String)
```

As you can see, replacing text only accepts a `String` and I cannot find way to replace it with an `NSAttributedString`.

One thing I could do is to store the whole `UITextView attributedText` and then perform the desired changes on a `NSMutableAttributedString` and then I can replace the `UITextView.attributedText` to be the one of the `NSMutableAttributedString`, but this comes with some issues for me.

If the text is already long with some `NSStorage` and `NSAttachments` this will be way more expensive.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can't intermix `String` and `NSAttributedString`, there's unfortunately no workaround that will let both co-exist in a text field.

But you should be able to use [`replaceCharacters(in:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1417045-replacecharacters):

```
existingAttributedString.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: replacementAttributedString)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! Yes I'll try the method you've suggested